# Is it possible to turn my home connection into a proxy? (Without access to modem)

Tags: networking

So I have port forwarded my home ip and connected with ssh. This ssh connection was converted into a socks5 proxy. I was able to do this from outside my network, anywhere.

I want to have this same proxy function without touching my modem settings. I dont need the ssh connection. I would like to know if something like this is possible and if it is, how I can do it.

Comment: Stack Overflow focuses on programming problems. Your networking problem seems better fit for [Network Engineering Stack Exchange](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/). If you have a programming problem, please include it in your post.

Comment: can someone move my question to networking?, if not Ill post it there in 40 minutes